# How to create DataTableConfig for a class with a ForeignCollection?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two legacy classes that I want to persist via **ormlite 4.48**.
Those classes can't be modified, so I **can't use the nice annotations**.

Fortunately, `DatabaseTableConfig` came to the rescue.

Here my classes:

```
public class RedditLink extends RedditType {

    // Thing
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String kind;
    private String data;

    // Votable
    private int ups;
    private int downs;
    // Uncomment if this ever matters private boolean likes;

    // Created
    private long created_utc;

    // Link
    private String author;
    private String domain;
    private int num_comments;
    private boolean over18;
    private boolean is_self;
    private String permalink;
    private String subreddit;
    private String subredditId;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private String selftext;

    private String thumbnail;

    private RedditLinkList list;

       ... Getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class RedditLinkList {

    private int id;

    public static final RedditLinkList EMPTY = new RedditLinkList();

    public Collection<RedditLink> links = new ArrayList<RedditLink>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<RedditLink> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Collection<RedditLink> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class rainstudios.kelo.data.model.RedditLinkList
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:215)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.fromClass(DatabaseTableConfig.java:146)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:53)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:151)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:107)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$4.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:907)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:907)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:70)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:297)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:201)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.doCreateDao(DaoManager.java:359)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:129)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:229)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:84)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ormlite.InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.createTableIfNotExists(InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.java:106)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ormlite.InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.initializeTablesIfNeeded(InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.java:120)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ormlite.InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.createObjectPersister(InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.java:69)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.CacheManager.getObjectPersister(CacheManager.java:183)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.CacheManager.loadDataFromCache(CacheManager.java:68)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.loadDataFromCache(DefaultRequestRunner.java:239)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:88)
    at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is the code I use to generate my `DatabaseFieldConfig` :

```
        //
        // Link
        //
        List<DatabaseFieldConfig> fieldConfigs = new ArrayList<DatabaseFieldConfig>();
        DatabaseFieldConfig field1 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("id");
        field1.setId(true);
        fieldConfigs.add(field1);

        DatabaseFieldConfig field2 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("name");
        field2.setCanBeNull(false);
        fieldConfigs.add(field2);

        DatabaseFieldConfig field3 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("url");
        fieldConfigs.add(field3);

        DatabaseFieldConfig field4 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("title");
        fieldConfigs.add(field4);

        DatabaseFieldConfig field6 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("author");
        fieldConfigs.add(field6);

        DatabaseFieldConfig field5 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("subreddit");
        fieldConfigs.add(field5);

        // @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true,
        // canBeNull =
        // true, columnName = "list_id")
        DatabaseFieldConfig field7 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("list");
        field7.setForeign(true);
        field7.setForeignAutoRefresh(true);
        field7.setCanBeNull(true);
        field7.setColumnName("list_id");

        fieldConfigs.add(field7);

        DatabaseTableConfig<RedditLink> link = new DatabaseTableConfig<RedditLink>(
                RedditLink.class, fieldConfigs);

        //
        // List
        //
        List<DatabaseFieldConfig> fieldListConfigs = new ArrayList<DatabaseFieldConfig>();
        DatabaseFieldConfig fieldList1;

        fieldList1 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("id");
        fieldList1.setColumnName("list_id");
        fieldList1.setGeneratedId(true);
        fieldListConfigs.add(fieldList1);

        DatabaseFieldConfig fieldList2 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("links");
        fieldList2.setForeignCollection(true);
        fieldList2.setForeignCollectionEager(false);
        fieldListConfigs.add(fieldList2);

        DatabaseTableConfig<RedditLinkList> list = new DatabaseTableConfig<RedditLinkList>(
                RedditLinkList.class, fieldListConfigs);
        // Cross references
        field7.setForeignTableConfig(list);
        fieldList2.setForeignTableConfig(link);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: my app uses `ormlite_config.txt` cache

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope. I tried some code but it dodn't work. So I moved on.

Comment: I've created an issue for this: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/38